# Mobile scroll bar preventing click event to propagate to element underneath it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small button that is very close to the right side of the page.
In a mobile browser as Safari iOS or Chrome the lateral vertical scroll bar thumb is overlapping the button. The problem is that when the thumb is on the button, the button is not clickable anymore because the browser thinks the user wants to move the scrollbar thumb.

This picture shows the scrollbar thumb when it overlaps the button:

[image]

Is there a way to disable the scrollbar or make the click/tap event propagate to the element underneath the bar?

I tried to work on all the css pseudo elements, but it looks that mobile browsers ignore those directives.

Thanks,

Comment: why can't you add 10 px of right margin?

Comment: Probably that's the only solution, but I wanted to use the entire lateral space on the viewport.

Comment: maybe hiding it? `::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}`

Comment: I tried that and it gets ignored on mobile. Thanks